# C++ Generic Linked List

Tags: c++, templates, generics, linked-list

For the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Foo2;
class Foo3;

template <class T>
class Foo1 {
  public:
    Foo1();
    void print() {
      cout << "My name is: " << name << endl;
    }

    T getNext(){
      return nextLink;
    }

    string name;
    T nextLink;

};

class Foo2 : public Foo1 {
  public:
    Foo2(){
      name = "Foo2";
    }
};


class Foo3 : public Foo1 {
  public:
    Foo3(){
      name = "Foo3";
    }
};

template <class T>
class LinkedList {



public:
    T curr;
    T first;

void add(T node){
  if(first == NULL){
    first = node
  }
  node->nextLink = this;
  curr = node;
}
T getNext(){
  return next;
}
void printAll(){
  T curr = first;
  cout << "Contents are: " ;
  while(curr != NULL){
    cout << curr.print() << ", ";
    curr = curr.getNext();
  }
}

};

int main() {
  LinkedList<?> list;
  list.add(new Foo2());
  list.add(new Foo3());
  list.printAll();
  return 0;
}
```

I'm attempting to implement a generic linked list, i realise that i could import `<list>` but that wouldn't suit my project. I'm trying to have a linked list of `Foo2` and `Foo3` objects - the above is the best i could accomplish as i'm new to C++.

Error:

```
generic.C: In instantiation of Foo1<Foo2>:
generic.C:26:   instantiated from here
generic.C:22: error: Foo1<T>::nextLink has incomplete type
generic.C:6: error: forward declaration of âclass Foo2
generic.C: In instantiation of Foo1<Foo3>:
generic.C:34:   instantiated from here
generic.C:22: error: Foo1<T>::nextLink has incomplete type
generic.C:7: error: forward declaration of class Foo3
generic.C: In member function void LinkedList<T>::add(T):
generic.C:50: error: expected ; before } token
generic.C: In member function T LinkedList<T>::getNext():
generic.C:55: error: ânextâ was not declared in this scope
generic.C: In function âint main()â:
generic.C:69: error: template argument 1 is invalid
generic.C:69: error: invalid type in declaration before â;â token
generic.C:70: error: request for member âaddâ in âlistâ, which is of non-class type âintâ
generic.C:71: error: request for member âaddâ in âlistâ, which is of non-class type âintâ
generic.C:72: error: request for member âprintAllâ in âlistâ, which is of non-class type âintâ
```

Comment: And what is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: homework? if not, why not use `std::list`?

Comment: Why doesn't `std::list` suit your needs?

Comment: Not homework - linked lists are easy, but not generic linked lists.

Comment: Saying `std::list` doesn't "suit your needs" is absurd. It is a well-implemented linked list. If you need a good linked list, that is what you should use. And if you need something else, then there's little point in trying to write your own linked list. I'm sorry, but there's a 99.9% chance that `std::list` *is* what you need. the last 0.01% is to cover the possibility that it isn't, and that then your own implementation won't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the "?" in LinkedList

If this is the case, then you should use `LinkedList<Foo1 *>`.

Why can't you use std::list? Maybe we can help you with that, it will be far better that using your own implementation.

Comment: I can't use std::list because i would like to create a LinkedList with has multiple possible choices for it's next node - of which it choces one randomly.

Comment: I see, how about using std::list<MultipleChoice>? This could let you use std::list and give you a group of "choices". I think the best would be to not think about the list and instead focus on abstracting your problem.

Comment: `MultipleChoice` ? Why not simply `std::list<boost::variant<Foo2, Foo3> >` ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a T*, not a T. Looks to me like you came from Java where everything is a reference. There is no `?` in C++ templates. I think that you need to pick up a book on basic C++ first, and then come back to templates.

Comment: The "?" is the to indicate my ignorance of what should be there.

Comment: @Kay: Oh ok. I thought you meant Java's `?` which is a valid generic argument. However, there's so much wrong in your code, you need a book.

Answer (score 2):

Despite your assertions to the contrary, the example you've given could be solved with `std::list`:

```
std::list<Foo1 *> list;

list.push_back(new Foo2());
list.push_back(new Foo3());

for (std::iterator<Foo1 *> it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
{
    (*it)->print();
}
```

Obviously, there's a potential memory leak here...

Answer (score 0):

Combining the bits, it seems like this should work:

```
int main() {
  std::list<boost::variant<Foo2, Foo3> > list;
  list.push_back(Foo2());
  list.push_back(Foo3());
  printAll(list); // You'd still need to write this obviously.
  return 0;
}
```